# Unity Render Distance Close

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering

[image]

Help. I was developing a game. And after some days i got this problem. At close range ground and everything other start disapear i need to see at close range to create animations and models. How do i fix this? i really need to see at close range. At far everything is ok i see everything but at close range it starts to disapear. In game everything is ok. Just in scene.

Problem is in the picture. I am near the ground in the picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If its the in game camera look in your inspector panel. On your camera game object there should be a property in the inspector name Clipping Planes, change the near one to something like 0.01[image]

If it's not your ingame camera and it's the camera in the scene view, just select an object and press F to reset clipping planes.

Comment: What camera? where do i find it?  i have main camera but its for game. i dont need to change that. The problem is with scene camera now i understand how do i find editor (scene) camera? not game main camera.

Comment: @herobrinebrotherzoro Hmmm, my bad. Select an object and press F, that will adjust the planes.